# How to enter linefeed in binary mode?

Tags: binary-file

Trying to find a linefeed within a binary file using `vim -b`, but any attempt at entering that byte value (e.g. control-v control-j, control-v 010, control-v u000a) turns into a NUL (`^@`) instead.

I've tried using vim 8.2.2029 and neovim v0.5.1 on MacOS Big Sur 11.6 along with vim 8.1.2269 in Ubuntu 20.04, observing the same behavior in each.

Comment: Not an answer but per `:h keycodes` this is apparently by design `<NL>  linefeed  CTRL-J  10 (used for <Nul>)`. Wonder why...

Comment: You could always temporarily filter the file through xxd (`:%!xxd`) and search for the hex value. Then undo to reverse. (Do NOT save! :)

Comment: Importantly that filtering is best done with `vim -b` or `:edit ++bin`; otherwise you are likely to corrupt the file. My [Hex plugin](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-hex) has some conveniences for that, but you still have to remember binary mode

Comment: Or rather corrupt the buffer contents since the file won't be impacted as long as no saving is done.

Comment: Apparently it's because lines are stored as NUL-terminated strings; it can't put an actual NUL character inside such a string, so it puts a LF instead. And the linefeeds in the file mark the boundaries between strings but are not themselves actually stored in memory – apparently not even in binary mode.
 ```<Nul>           zero                    CTRL-@    0 (stored as 10) *<Nul>*```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently by design. Internally, each line of the file is stored as a NUL-terminated string. The actual linefeeds from a file are not stored at all; they simply delimit the strings when a buffer is read from or written to a file. LF-valued bytes only show up in buffer memory to represent NULs, since there's no way to put a literal zero byte inside a NUL-terminated string.

So I guess the way to search for a linefeed value even in binary mode is to do a regex search for end-of-line (`$`).